# Water colour Effect for iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview

can anyone help me in finding the best algorithm for Water Colour effect. We have application like "Waterlogue" working on this effect. I have to implement this in one of my projects. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please explain what you have tried. This is not a site for requesting free work

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am trying this "CIFilter" class, but did't worked out. Would certainly need your guidance here. Thanks

Comment: @adao7000 can you please suggest anything. Thanks.